# How to change Mui DataGrid Toolbar label and input placeholder text?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

[image: DatagridToolbar]

I am currently using React MUI. I added toolbar button to my datagrid. In toolbar panel there is default "Find column" label and "Column title" input placeholder values. How can I change/replace those values?

I tried in sx prop giving to label class css -> content: "some value" but it did not work.

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? Currently its really hard to recreate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize these texts by passing `columnsPanelTextFieldLabel` and `columnsPanelTextFieldPlaceholder` keys through `localeText` parameter like this:

```
<DataGrid
    {...data}
    slots={{
      toolbar: GridToolbar
    }}
    localeText={{
      columnsPanelTextFieldLabel: "Custom Find Column",
      columnsPanelTextFieldPlaceholder: "Custom Column Title"
    }}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-toolbar-label-customization?file=src%2FApp.tsx) for a live working example.
You can take a look at [this link](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/cc09f3788d65f9694a0fbc1381681c701b802e47/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/constants/localeTextConstants.ts) for the full list of customizable texts.